# Query to compare differences of two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, union

I am attempting to create a UNION ALL query, on two differently named columns in two different tables.

I would like to take the "MTRL" column in the table USER_EXCEL and compare it against the "short_material_number" column from the IM_EXCEL table. I would then like the query to only return the *differences* between the two columns.  Both columns house material numbers but are named differently (column wise) in the tables.

What I have so far is:

```
 (SELECT [MTRL] FROM dbo.USER_EXCEL
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT [short_material_number] FROM dbo.IM_Excel) 

 UNION ALL

(SELECT [short_material_number] FROM dbo.IM_Excel
 EXCEPT 
 SELECT [MTRL] FROM dbo.USER_EXCEL)
```

However, when trying to run that query I receive an error message that states:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 22
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: My guess is that one of the columns contain numeric values and the other texts. The query is implicitly trying to convert the text to a numeric value and one of the records contains a text value that cannot be converted.

Comment: @Barry Yeah, that's it. For sure.

Comment: Please add the data types of `MTRL` and `short_material_number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost certainly getting this error because one of your two columns is a `FLOAT` data type, while the other is `VARCHAR`.  [This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/data-conversion-in-sql-server/) would be a good place to start reading about implicit conversions, which happen when you try to compare two columns that are of different data types.

To get this working, you need to convert the float to a varchar, like in the example below.

```
 (
    SELECT [MTRL] FROM dbo.USER_EXCEL
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT CAST([short_material_number] AS VARCHAR(18)) FROM dbo.IM_Excel
  )

 UNION ALL

  (
    SELECT CAST([short_material_number] AS VARCHAR(18)) FROM dbo.IM_Excel
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT [MTRL] FROM dbo.USER_EXCEL
  )
```

Comment: thank you everyone.. i am new to SQL querying so still learning.  Thank you again.

Comment: Happy to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: and it was the IM_EXCEL table (short_material_number) that was float.. as i look into it now.  MTRL column is varchar(18)

Answer (score 0):

From you question I understand you are trying to compare two columns but returning only one column I would recommend you to use following query to compare the differences side by side

```
SELECT  ue.[MTRL], ie.[short_material_number]
FROM dbo.IM_Excel ie
FULL OUTER JOIN 
dbo.USER_EXCEL ue 
ON CAST(ie.[short_material_number] AS VARCHAR(20)) =  ue.[MTRL]
WHERE ie.[short_material_number] IS NULL
OR  ue.[MTRL] IS NULL
```